# Express and EJS- Does not compile. How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

So, I'm trying to make a website using Express and EJS. But recently, after changing literally nothing, a much of errors related to EJS and the tags. Here's an example.

```
<% include partials/header %>

<h1>Landing page!</h1>

<p>Welcome to PERSCOM</p>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

But I get this error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in G:\perscom\perscom\views\landing.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass async: true as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12)
    at Object.compile (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:389:16)
    at handleCache (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:212:18)
    at tryHandleCache (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at G:\perscom\perscom\routes\index.js:9:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at G:\perscom\perscom\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

There is a similar error on any page that uses EJS tags if I remove them the issue is fixed. How can I fix this?

Header

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PERSCOM</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>



          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/landing">PERSCOM</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/listusers">Show Members</a>
                </li>
                <%(currentUser) {%>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="opcenter">Operations Center</a>
                </li>
                <%}%>
            </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <%if(!currentUser) { %>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
                        </li>
                    <% } else { %>
                        <span class="navbar-text">Signed in as <span style="font-weight: 800; color:black;"><%=currentUser.username%></span></span>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    <% }  %>                  
                </ul>             

            </div>
          </nav>
```

Footer

```
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the content of the `landing.ejs` file the one you posted? If it is, add the code of the two includes.

Comment: Yes it is. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Did you set [express view engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)?

Comment: Should not there be an `if` here? `<%(currentUser) {%>`

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm so dumb I should've really checked it.